# Looking for details on how Linux kernel works with NVME

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am looking for documentations or talks that explains in details how Linux kernel works with NVME. For example, if an application tries to maximize the parallel IO capabilities on NVME, what are the best practices and why? NVME claims to have 64k queues and each queue supports 64k commands. If an application issues writes in parallel to 200 different files, does that means NVME can easily handle the parallel write at queue level because it has 64k queues per drive? How are these 64k queues map to storage unit such as blocks? I would like to see a reference that talks NVME's physical internals and how Linux OS and driver uses it in reality in a comprehensive way and explain from the ground up. So far, I have only see some pieces of information but not explained in a whole package. Thanks

Comment: I am in your same situation, and it's a pity there is nothing from the developer side. The best explanation I have found is here http://sklinuxblog.blogspot.com/2018/08/linux-kernel-nvme-driver.html where this guy does a reverse engineering (through following the source and ftrace)